# Akka Pattern - Actor tree, propagate in the tree

Tags: java, tree, akka

[image]

```
I want implement this flow by Akka Stream. 
The root is number 1, I would like to be able to send a message to these children and that these children to these children with this type of message.
   1->2
   1->5
   1->2->3
   1->-2->4
1->5->6
```

The problem is that I don't understand anything about Akka.

Answer (score 0):

To do the above, you can just define one actor type which has children as his state, and when receiving some defined message passes down that message to its children. U just need to set the correct children of the same type with their respective children then.
Akka-stream is not needed/useful here.